# ASP.NET with MVC 2 in VS2010

Tags: c#

Hi
i want to do a work in asp.net using mvc and ajax
i have a button
when i click that button,its text should be changed.e.g before click(Click me) after click(u clicked me)
but i want to do this work in MVC2
i have studied but couldn't understood mvc
kinfly do this example so that i can understand it easily

Best Regards:
Shaahan

Comment: You need to study ASP.Net MVC harder.  You probably also need to learn the basics of HTTP, HTML, and Javascript.

Comment: i think it would be useful for u to start with some simple asp.net mvc app, check out the nerd dinner, it's has more than enough features to keep u busy :)

Answer (score 0):

are u just trying to change the text label on click?

there's a few ways to do this, but you can probably just use an onclick event and change the label straight when the user click on the button.

[for example like so.](http://jsfiddle.net/ZSEUA/)

but if you want to do it MVC just for the heck of it, then you can create a view, click on the button and do a form post to the same page, and on the controller use ViewData["ButtonLabel"] and update the button label when the page goes back :P

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want simply with javascript.  If you want to learn mvc here a simple [music store][1] tutorial that I has helped me a lot!    [1]: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-1

Answer (score 0):

MVC stands for Model, View, Controller.

The way this works is you have a controller, say HomeController which is a class derived from Controller. When you access /Home/ on the site through your browser it serves the browser a view and any additional information, often cookies and such. The model is the data and logic of the program, often handling things like databases.

There are multiple ways to go about this example.

```
//In HomeController class
public ActionResult Index()
{
   return View();
}

public ActionResult Clicked()
{
   return View()
}
```

And then for the Views for the index view you'd have a button which would link to /Home/Clicked. Then on the clicked view you'd have the button with changed text.

Of course this is only one way to do it you could just append a number do the /Home/ url and pass that to the view and if it's not 0 have the test be different or use javascript to change the button's text

Index view:

```
<form>
<input type="button" value="NClicked" onclick="window.location.href='/Home/Clicked'"> 
</form>
```

Clicked view:

```
<form>
<input type="button" value="Clicked" onclick="window.location.href='/Home/'"> 
</form>
```

Of course there's more to the views than that, but you can insert that into your body.